# I am unable to change for loop into while loop in php?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I am new working on my college project to print some data but I am too confused to changed `for` loop into `while` loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($labels);$i++) {     
    for($j=0;$j<count($dd1);$j++) {
        $temp = explode(">",$dd1[$j]);    
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I am clueless so i haven't tried i mean i don't know how to initiate

Answer (score 1):

I know this question would soon disappear, due to the nature of the question. I understand you are new to programming, so I won't be harsh at you :)
But I would like to help.
To convert any for loop to while in any common programming language (Dont hit me hard for this line)

- declare and initiate counter variable outside the loop
- while check condition
- loop logic
- increment counter

Example :

```
$j = 0;
while($j<count($dd1)) {
// loop logic
$j++
}
```